# progressbar in android with thread

Tags: android

I am build one application in which, I can get data from a server so simply I want to put progress bar on it but I can't give specific time duration. it is dismiss randomly while fetch entire data from server. so can you tell me how can I do this ?

can you give one simple example with elaboration

Comment: Why don't you use the loading with the circle gif thingy instead? You can't have a progress bar without knowing how long it will take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_detail);

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "Loading ....", true,true);
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);  //Implment Runnable;
    thread.start();
    //      setData();
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    //Do your all work except User Interface Updation
    han.sendEmptyMessage(0);

}
private Handler han=new Handler()
{

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
    dismiss dialog  
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html sample but it's better to integrate with async task [Example of async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and since you don't know how long it will take just use the `onPostExecute` to close the progress.
 hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to combine `AsynTask` and [indeterminate ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ProgressBar3.html) together. Something like this:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<...> {

 private ProgressDialog progressBar;

 protected void onPreExecute() {
     progressBar = ...;
     progressBar.show();
 }

 protected Long doInBackground() {
     // blah blah
 }

 protected void onPostExecute() {
     progressBar.dismiss();
 }
}
```

Don't forget to handle if user wants to cancel the progress.

Answer (score 1):

U can use AsyncTask

```
private class Myclass extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

 ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
     pDialog= ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "loading...");
     pDialog.show();
super.onPreExecute();
 }

@Override
 protected Long doInBackground(Void... unused) {
     // your code here
return null;
 }

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
     pDialog.dismiss();
 }
}
```